# Using ContourPlot3D with extrusion in Printout3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, 3d-printing

I am joining two 3D contour plots using the `Show` command, and then I want to use `Printout3D` to generate a .stl file. I have:

```
first = ContourPlot3D[
  z Sin[Pi x] == -((Sqrt[44 + y^2] - y) x^2 + y) Cos[Pi x], {x, 0, 
   1}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -150, 150}, Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .05}]

second = ContourPlot3D[-z Sin[
     Pi x] == -((Sqrt[44 + y^2] + y) x^2 - y) Cos[Pi x], {x, -1, 
   0}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -150, 150}, Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .05}]
```

Then I just use `Show` and `Printout3D`:

```
combined = Show[first, second, PlotRange -> All]
 
Printout3D[combined, "combined.stl"]
```

It loads for 20 minutes and then produces the error:

> **"Printout3D :  A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of Printout3D"**.

At first I thought the error had to do with differing x-domains but I made some tweaks and I got the same error. How can I specify a region at Position 1.

Thanks for any help!